# jQuery slide doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, jquery-slide-effects

I have a problem with jQuery and I don't know where comes from, here is what is in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'
script_16.js:46Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'
script_16.js:46Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'
script_16.js:46Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'
script_16.js:46Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElement'
homepage:321GET http://shoppingkatalog.com/modules/mod_ice_jshopping_categories/assets/images/next.png 404 (Not Found)
all.js:54FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
beacon.js:1GET http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=8&c2=2101&c3=1234567891234567891&ns__t=1349547316971&ns_c=ISO-8859-1&c8=&c7=http%3A%2F%2Fdg.specificclick.net%2F%3Fy%3D3%26t%3Dh%26u%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fshoppingkatalog.com%252Fhomepage%26r%3D&c9=http%3A%2F%2Fshoppingkatalog.com%2Fhomepage 
homepage:113Uncaught ReferenceError: checkCookie is not defined
homepage:392Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getElements'
```

[Here is the link from the page](http://shoppingkatalog.com/homepage), please help me solve the problem

Comment: @harsha it worked fine until I installed one plugin, and uninstalling it didn't fix the problem. I think its some kind of jquery mixup but I cant solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem installing [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) joomla plugin. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because the function cannot be found at the time of execution.  So try moving the file script_16.js lower in your list of JS files called on the page.  I think it is a matter of defining the function earlier on the page.